# C++: Design suggestions to handle many configuration variables

Tags: c++, oop, configuration, refactoring

I m refactoring a legacy codebase. They had 100+ public config variables and 90+ methods for the functionality in a single class. I m in the process of breaking down the large class into multiple small classes based on the features.
Since these config variables are read from a config file and set to these variables , i end up in writing a lot of getter and setter methods.
Is this is a good design to have so many setter and getters instead of direct assignment?
Any good design recommendations are welcome.
Below is a code snippet
EDIT:

```
class config {
public:
void Setvalue(int val) {value_ = val;}
int Getvalue(){return value_;}
void SetisEnabled(bool value) {isEnabled_ = value;}
bool GetisEnabled() {return isEnabled_; }
void SetorgCity(string city) {orgCity_ = city; } 
string GetorgCity(){return orgCity_;}
void SetorgState(string state) {orgState_ = state; } 
string GetorgState(){return orgState_;}
..
private:
    int value_;
    bool isEnabled_;
    string orgCity_;
    string orgState_;
    string orgCounty_;
    string orgName_;
    string mytypeval1_;
    string mytypeval2_;
    string mytypeval3_;
    string mytypeval4_;
}

or 

class Config
{
    int value_;
    bool isEnabled_;
    string orgCity_;
    string orgState_;
    string orgCounty_;
    string orgName_;
    string mytypeval1_;
    string mytypeval2_;
    string mytypeval3_;
    string mytypeval4_;
}

Config sampleConfig;
sampleConfig.isEnabled_ = true;
sampleConfig.value_ = 1234;
...
```

Comment: to answer the question one would need to know why you think you need to write lots of getters and setters. If that feels wrong to you just don't do it...

Comment: this would be easier to answer with some example code

Comment: reading from file is usually done with an `operator>>`, and is rather orthogonal to writing getters/setters or not

Comment: If you are interested or even using an underlying framework, QSettings is a class which provides an interface for such tasks: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#details

Answer (score 3):

> Is this is a good design to have so many setter and getters instead of direct assignment?

There's absolutely nothing wrong with using a simple `struct`s for storing data:

```
struct SomeData
{
    std::string some_name;
    int some_value;
    float another_value;
}
```

since `struct` members default to `public` you can then simply write:

```
SomeData mydata;
mydata.some_name = "a name";
...
std::cout << mydata.some_value;
```

Comment: He could also make the members public in the class

Comment: @RoQuOTriX the members are public in the class in this answer...

Comment: Yes I know taht, but maybe some of his classes are implementing methods, then maybe (depends on design) he wants to use a class instead of struct (i know that there  isn't a difference, only the accessor)

Comment: @RoQuOTriX The OP is specifically about storing data with accessors. Not encapsulating it. If the data needs to be encapsulated than the `struct` that stores it can be made a `private` member of *another* `class` that implements behavior..

Comment: Making the it struct would limit me from abstraction and other future extensions.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is for your `config` class to have an operation called, say, `initFromConfig()` that initialises all its instance variables from an external configuration file. Doing this will remove the need to have setter operations.

Also,it is more efficient for the getter operations to return `const string &` rather than `string`.

With the above two changes made, your `config` class would look like the following:

```
class config {
public:
  initFromConfigFile(const string & fileName); // initialises foo_ and bar_
  const string & getFoo() { return foo_; }
  const string & getBar() { return bar_; }
private:
  string  foo_; 
  string  bar_; 
};
```